# Corrupted size vs. prev_size in c with dynamic input function

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, pass-by-value

I wrote a function to dynamic input a string in c but when i run the program and i write something whit more than about 15 char i get "corrupted size vs. prev_size" i don't understand why.

```
int main()
{
    char *text = malloc(sizeof(char));
    while(1)
    {
        dynInput(text);
        printf("%s\n", text);
    }
}

void dynInput(char *text)
{
    for(int l = 1, i = 0; 1; l++, i++)
        {
            text[i] = getchar();
            text = realloc(text, sizeof(char) * l);
            if(text[i] == '\n')
            {
                text[i] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Show a minimal complete program that demonstrates how the function is called.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i added the main

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `text` defined in main is passed to the function by value.

It means that the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer, Changing the copy within the function does not change the original pointer.

So this statement

```
printf("%s\n", text);
```

invokes undefined behavior because after the function call the `text` has an invalid value. The memory initially pointed to by the pointer was reallocated.

You need to pass the pointer by reference. In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Dereferencing the pointer within the function you will get an access to the original object.

So the function should be declared like

```
void dynInput(char **text);
```

and called like

```
dynInput(&text);
```

However it is better when the function creates and returns a pointer.

So it is better to declare the function like

```
char * dynInput( void );
```

and call it like

```
char *text = dynInput();
```